# Has anyone been beamed into the future or past in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager

Has anyone been beamed into the future or past on purpose or by accident? Or is this even considered possible in any Star Trek universe?

In this question it states how beaming works, [Why do people step to positions to be transported, even if there isn't a transporter pad?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20353/why-do-people-step-to-positions-to-be-transported-even-if-there-isnt-a-transpo)

From the question above:

> A typical transport sequence began with a coordinate lock, during
>   which the destination was verified and programmed, via the targeting
>   scanners. Obtaining or maintaining a transporter lock enables the
>   transporter operator to know the subject's location, even in motion,
>   allowing the beaming process to start more quickly. This is an
>   essential safety precaution when a starship away team enters a
>   potentially dangerous situation that would require an emergency
>   beam-out.
>
> A transporter lock was usually maintained by tracing the homing signal
>   of a communicator or combadge. When there was a risk that such devices
>   would be lost in the field or are otherwise unavailable, personnel
>   could be implanted with a subcutaneous transponder before an away
>   mission, to still provide a means to maintain a transporter lock.
>   Alternatively, sensors could be used to scan for the biosign or energy
>   signature of a subject, which could then be fed into the transporter's
>   targeting scanner for a lock.

So it seems the transporter is guided by co-ordinates, which means it is not line of sight (Correct me if I am misinterpreting this) What I was thinking was  there was a possibility that co-ordinates(spacial and time) in the future could be used to transport someone there. If this makes it harder or easier for say ,something like being beamed into the past or future, regardless if it was only minutes or even distant future or past.

### Has anyone ever had been beamed into the future or past in Star Trek?

Comment: “So it seems the transporter is guided by co-ordinates, which means it is not line of sight... If this makes it harder or easier for say ,something like being beamed into the past or future” — I’ve no idea what you’re getting at here.

Comment: I don’t see how it would affect it either way. Star Trek’s transporters move objects through space. The co-ordinates (presumably) define which points in space those objects are moved to and from, just like latitude and longitude co-ordinates define a place on the earth’s surface.

Comment: Does Captain Scott count when he put himself into the buffer for like 75 years? Time travel into the future is not only possible, it's a requirement ;)

Comment: The Entropy Effect (Vonda N. McIntyre) was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: According to Star Trek Technical Manuals I used to have, the Enterprise skin is transparent to the transporter beams in very specific spots below each of the transporter rooms, this implies that it is in fact line-of-sight.

Comment: @Octopus I've not seen that. Do you know which Technical Manual it was?

Comment: @zabeus, its actually in the "Star Trek Blueprints--General Plans, Constitution Class, USS Enterprise" drawn by Franz Joseph Designs. Not a book or manual, but a set of fold out deck plans and cross sections I've had since the 80s. I went and dug them out. On deck 8 there are 3 emergency xporters and below them on deck 9 it says "skin transparent to energy", Again on deck 10 there is a cargo xporter and below on deck 11 it says the same thing. Also on deck 23 a cargo xporter, same thing. There may be other spots. Those are the ones I found just now.

Comment: They beamed into a parallel universe in  -- Mirror, Mirror

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## Yes, it happened both by accident and on purpose

### By accident

The two-part episode [DS9: Past Tense](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Past_Tense,_Part_I_(episode)).

> During a transporter accident above Earth in the USS Defiant caused by
> chroniton particles, **Benjamin Sisko, Julian Bashir, and Jadzia Dax**
> were sent back in time to mid 21st century, just before the Bell
> Riots.

It was later discovered that the chronitron particles, which were lodged in the Defiant's ablative armor and were emitted by its cloaking device, were responsible for shifting the transported personell in time.

Also, in the same episode **Kira Nerys and Miles O'Brien** travelled through time to several different years (1930s, 1967, 2048 and finally, 2024). Their travel was, however, intentional.

It is also interesting that:

> While devising "Past Tense, Part I", the writing staff of Star Trek:
> Deep Space Nine chose the transporter as a form of time travel which
> hadn't been employed before and wouldn't require much exposition. "We
> had never used the transporters to beam people back in time, which I
> thought would be kind of a neat way to do it," stated Robert Hewitt
> Wolfe, who co-wrote the story for "Past Tense, Part I" and co-wrote
> the episode's teleplay. [(Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Companion, p. 197)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_Companion)

### On purpose

The Federation timeship 'Relativity' from 29th century was equipped with a temporal transporter, which was capable of transporting an individual in both time and space. It was seen in [VOY: Relativity](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Relativity_(episode)).

> The timeship Relativity was equipped with a temporal transporter,
> located at the starboard-aft of their bridge. The transporter was used
> in unison with several other technologies, such as temporal sensors
> and temporal shields. Temporal sensors allowed for the precise moment
> and location to be chosen, and temporal shields were raised before
> making any temporal transports.
>
> When Captain Braxton, commander of the Relativity, attempted to save
> the Starship Voyager from destruction due to a temporal incursion, he
> used a temporal transporter to beam back and retrieve **Seven of Nine**
> moments before the ship exploded.

As mentioned above, **Kira Nerys and Miles O'Brien** travelled intentionally in search for Benjamin Sisko, Julian Bashir and Jadzia Dax.

I have highlighted the people transported, as Kyloren rephrased his question.

Comment: Nice work! I could not find a thing.

Comment: There's also *TNG "Relics"*, in which Scotty is found stored in a transporter buffer, which, depending on your definition, could be considered using a transporter to reach the future. It's just taking the slow route.

Comment: @anaximander  have to disagree, as we know, there is always a delay (for the external observer) during the transportation, so using your definition, we would have to assume that every person transported is a time traveller, even if it is just for a few seconds.

Comment: @Monte Cristo- how long is that buffer delay compared to relativity? if you were instantly transported (faster than light) you would arrive at point B before you left point A. The amount of time traveled would be in proportion to distance.  for example, Transwarp beaming can transport across great distances in the brief time it takes a computer to read your pattern from the buffer. In terms of relativistic physics, any movement in space is also movement in time, so every transport time travels to a degree.

Answer (score 13):

In the voyager episode Eye of the Needle a probe got stuck in a wormhole. A Romulan ship discovers the probe and the crews make contact.

A transporter relay is set up via the probe and after some tests the romulan captain beams over to voyager. There is talk of using this as a method to return Voyagers crew to the Alpha quadrant.

It is later discovered that the wormhole in question travels not just through space but also through time. The Romulan is beamed back to his ship (and hence back in time) and the crews part ways.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess technically it's the wormhole that's doing the time stuff not the beaming—but they are still being beamed into the past/future

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this counts but I know that Scotty was trapped in a transporter beam during an attack. He was later recovered but a lot of time had passed. It was Picard's crew that found Scotty

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Could possibly add which episode this happened and possibly some relevant dialogue?

Comment: Nitpick, but in "Relics" he was held in suspension, he didn't time travel.

Comment: Hence the reason why I didn't know if it counted.

Comment: @Valorum he did travel into the future. Just happens that his time speed multiplier was 1

Comment: I don't recall the episode perfectly, but if memory serves, Scotty was not aware of the passage of time while he was de-materialized.  So you could say that from **his** perspective, he did travel into the future.

Comment: I'd agree that this doesn't count. Cryogenic suspension doesn't count as time travel either, even if it does feel_ that way. (See also Futurama.)

Comment: This was certainly one event that I considered when I read the question. I thought he wasn't so much trapped though. If I remember his story correctly, he intentionally used the beam to hide himself/hold himself until help arrived. I would totally count this as time travel. ...must view this episode again.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in Star Trek TOS; the [Assignment: Earth episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Assignment:_Earth_%28episode%29);

In this episode, Gary Seven accidentally beams aboard the Enterprise from over 1000 light years away. The crew speculates that the transport beam even traveled through time; because even in Kirk's time, no culture had the ability to go beaming around the universe.

**UPDATE:** Just to clarify, Gary Seven's technology is far more advanced than the Federation's so that implies Gary is from a time far in the future OR his home world is way more advanced than anyone else. I always assumed the former and not the latter.

If you recall, Gary is a completely optimized human who is also immune to the Vulcan nerve pinch. With all these advances, I'm forced to conclude Gary is from a time well beyond Kirk's.

Comment: Except that there's no evidence of his having time traveled and later canon (The Star Trek Abrams films) show that inter-system beaming is perfectly possible.

Comment: I wouldn't count the Abrams films as a counter argument, as it has been proven several times that there is a difference in technologies due to the Narada and Spock Prime's influence. After all, Spock had to show Pegg-Scotty the equation for long distance beaming.

Comment: There was Gary's comment of "In this time period, there weren't (notices Spock) **Humans** with a **Vulcan**? You're from the **future**, Captain." Though that doesn't prove he beamed through time, just that he has somehow been to the future.

Comment: @HannoverFist: I thought Gary was just stating that Kirk is not from 1968 while not giving away what time period he is from. Gary is clearly from Kirk's time or beyond. I always assumed Gary is from even further in the future

Comment: @Valorum et al. Writers from all kinds of shows have been notoriously bad at continuity. There's just too much to account for; that's why we have stackexchange... ;)

Comment: @djm - I assumed that Gary was contemporaneous but had knowledge of the future.

Comment: @Valorum - Gary claims he was from 20th Century Earth:

`SEVEN: Careful, Isis. All right. Captain Kirk. My name is Gary Seven. I am a human being from the twentieth century. I was on my way 
 
KIRK: Humans of the twentieth century do not go beaming around the galaxy, Mister Seven. 
 
SEVEN: I've been living on another planet far more advanced. I was beaming to Earth when you intercepted me. `

Comment: @Valorum: Wow I completely missed that! So he's working for extremely advanced aliens.

Comment: @djm - Yup. Abducted from their home planets and made to work as secret agents for some purpose. Was it for good or evil? You'd have to watch "*Gary Seven"* to find out. Alas, it was cancelled before it even got commissioned.

Comment: As I remember it, from MANY years ago: In the James Blish short story adaptation of "Assignment: Earth", Scotty said that it was at least theoretically possible to beam through time, but nobody'd ever done it.  He added that nobody had ever been able to put anywhere near that much power into a transporter beam, either.

Comment: @Valorum - and now his cat is trying to destroy the world.

Comment: @HannoverFist - I challenge you to show me a cat that isn't secretly planning that.

Comment: @Valorum, Abrams crap doesn't count as canon. just cause its called Star Ttrek doesn't mean that any of it is in any way consistent with the rest of the ST universe.

Comment: Non-canon but one of the novels (Assignment: Eternity) establishes that Gary Seven's jurisdiction as a "supervisor" extended not just spatially but temporally as well. And I think Valorum was making an ISIS joke.

Comment: @Valorum: Actually, that film showed that inter-system beaming was, in the original timeline, not yet possible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Not yet possible...for the Federation

Comment: @Valorum: Okay I did misread 'possible' for 'known' 